# Stop Listview Cell from refreshing upon scrolling in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I had a Listview with Toggle Button on each row.On Scrolling the Listview got refreshed, therefore the value Toggle Button also getchanged on each time it is scrolled?

I want to keep that Toggle button value either ON/OFF as it set by the user before scrolling?

Comment: Add some code and show us what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

```
On Scrolling the Listview got refreshed,
```

It is the defualt behaviour of the `ListView`. It actually not refreshed, `ListView` only have  the visible(with some offset) `Views` in the memory. and destroy others.

```
I want to keep that Toggle button value
```

You need to keep track off the states of the toggle buttons. Like store in `Local` arrayList. And update the `togglebutton` state in `getView` method of your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

try this in first line of getView Function

```
    if (convertView != null) return convertView;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you toggle your button, you should also refresh your adapter's data source. For e.g if you are using an arraylist to populate the adapter, on toggle on the button, you have to update your arraylist.

Preventing refresh of the list view can also be achieved if you prevent recycling of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your ListView to use `setChoiceMode()` (with `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` or `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`) and use a custom row layout that implements Checkable, this way the ListView will remember which rows have been toggled for you.

I detailed how to create a custom Checkable layout before in [CheckedTextView checkmark in ListView row not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12125792/1267661). (It's not that hard and this approach allows you to use any built-in adapter without having to extend it.)

Answer (score 0):

Use following: This will take care of your listView.

```
View vi = convertView;

if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutFile, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.layout1 = (LinearLayout) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.layoutcourse);
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.status = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.img_status);
            holder.date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date1);
            holder.toggleButton = (ImageView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else

            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
```

Comment: Where should I add this code? Also please describe the variables you have used in this code.

Comment: in your adapter in getView() method, this should be first line of code

Comment: Inside this method: public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { }

Comment: in getView() we have three agruments position,view & viewGroup. I can get the postion of the toggle button, view is for status than what is view Group

Comment: @SumitSharma This is an good example of how to use a ViewHolder, but it does not address restoring the state of a ToggleButton...

Comment: When listView is scrolled, if view is already created, the view does not refresh itself if above method is used and if, the view is not refreshed, the toggle buttons' state will not change

Comment: That's a really bad answer: Way to broad and really not helpful because no explanation which has anything to say about the toggle button problem.